# Chat Issue when sending memojis

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, sockets

I am implementing chat feature in ios app I am working as backend developer working on nodejs sockets. when my ios partner send memojis as the message the socket function recieve it as empty or OBJ. it is displayed as sticker it show empty response.

does anyone who worked on memojis can help me to know what could be the issue?

Comment: it is not displaying sticker it display empty response

Answer (score 0):

use emojis utf8 code , and encode while sending and decode while receiving..